# comparing java UI frameworks

Tags: jakarta-ee, user-interface, frameworks

I'm trying to find a precise comparison of JavaEE user interface frameworks and tools.

So far I've been working with symfony/PHP and RoR - these frameworks are provided with ORM, template engine, MVC engine and so on. It's very uncommon that you don't use framework's built-in templating engine and choose one on your own. In Java - that's the opposite, as I can see - frameworks are usually not bundled with one specific solution, and you've got to choose right tools for you.

I'm new to JavaEE and it's difficult to choose from so many tools available. So far I became familiar with  spring mvc, jsp and apache tiles. Also, I read that there are also: velocity, freemaker, sitemesh, jsf, facelets, tapestry, themyleaf... and many, many more. Moreover, some of them are defined as layout engines, others as template engines, etc. (in symfony/PHP you've got everything already configured with the main framework so you don't have to distinguish).

Do you know any comparison on Java web tools (preferably up-to-date, e.g. struts seem to fade away)? Something for a beginner ;)

edit: I did a research - found quite a lot of docs on each of those frameworks, but I'd have to spend a lot of time to learn all of them instead of getting a basic understanding and being able to compare them. I'm not looking for docs of a particular tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true there are many alternatives in Java, but there is a clear standard full stack framework and that is simply called Java EE.

It contains an MVC framework (JSF), a templating engine (Facelets), a depency injection facility (CDI), support for business logic and transactions (EJB) and a ORM (JPA),

It's a very rich framework and can be quite small. TomEE implements it all in some 25 MB.

All the other things you mention are alternatives. Simplest thing is to start with the standard framework (just download an implementation like TomEE or GlassFish). Worry about choosing alternatives when you have some experience and when you are for some reason not satisfied with the things in the standard framework/library.

Comment: I found your answer clear, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider using JSF, it has various flavors: IceFaces, MyFaces, PrimeFaces etc.....  Also GWT (Google Web Toolkit) is a great UI framework.

I would say GWT and JSF are comparable in ramp up time for learning.  Both of these frameworks work great with a Java EE project, and they even work great for a non-enterprise project, so it's really up to you after you familiarize yourself with them.  good luck!

Comment: Note that both IceFaces and PrimeFaces are add-ons; component libraries, while MyFaces is a JSF core implementation (like Mojarra, the RI).

Comment: Well put!  I'll be sure to remember that distinction.

Answer (score 0):

GWT webpages layer isn't Java EE. Only service layer is Java EE.